A conceptual misunderstanding in limits and geometric series
So, it starts off like this:
My friends told me that the floor function of 0.9 repeating (a.k.a. 0.99999.... ) is 0, which is factually untrue since 0.9 repeating is known and proven to be exactly equal to 1, and the floor of 1 is 1.
Their argument stated that since 0.9 repeating could be represented as the geometric series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{9}{10^{n}}$, and the sum to infinity $\frac{a}{1-r}$ only tends towards 1 per the infinite geometric series derivation.
The infinite geometric series is derived by the geometric series formula $\frac{a\left(1-r^{n}\right)}{1-r}$ when |r|< 1 and n tends towards infinity. Since n can't exactly be infinity (per the limit), r too can't exactly be 0, and hence, they state that the geometric series is imprecise and thus, 0.9 repeating isn't exactly equal to 1. Only is its limit equal to 1.
I argued if 0.9 repeating and 1 are distinct numbers, there must be another distinct real number between the two and they countered by saying "just add another 9 in the infinite string of nines (e.g. 0.99 repeating), since some infinities are bigger than others, like as you know, the numbers between 0 and 1 must be less than the numbers between 0 and 2 despite both being infinite" and they requested a formal proof.
So what exactly is going wrong here?

Welcome to Math.SE! ... "[T]hey state that the geometric series is imprecise and thus, $0.9$ repeating isn't exactly equal to $1$. Only is its limit equal to $1$." ... Well, when we write "$0.999\ldots$" (outside of non-standard analysis contexts), we mean the limit of the geometric series, so it would appear that everyone agrees! :)

You are right, and your counter-argument saying "if $1≠0.999\ldots,$ then find a number between them" is a smart one. Also, I'm not sure about the claim "the numbers between $0$ and $1$ must be less than the numbers between $0$ and $2.$" The sets $[0,1]$ and $[0,2]$ have the same cardinality (granted, cardinality isn't the only way to measure the "size" of a set, but it's the most widely used notion for the "size" of a set).

As for a formal proof, there is nothing more to be done. The very definition of $0.999\ldots$ is that it's $\lim_{N\to\infty}\sum_{n=1}^N\frac{9}{10^n},$ as @Blue mentioned above.

As for the whole floor function thing, the floor of $\sum_{n=1}^N\frac{9}{10^n}$ for any natural number $N$ is $0.$ However, the floor of the limit is $1.$ This happens precisely because the floor function is discontinuous at integers (here, it happens since it's discontinuous at $1.$)

@32Bit, comments cannot be marked as answers. If you wish, I can write up everything I've said in the comments as an answer.

Sure thing ,thanks!

You are right, in that $0.999\ldots=1.$ This is because, the standard definition of $0.999\ldots$ is that it's equal to
$$\lim_{N\to\infty}\sum_{n=1}^N\frac{9}{10^n}.$$
Like you noted, the partial sum can be evaluated using the GP formula:
$$\sum_{n=1}^N\frac{9}{10^n}=\frac{10^N-1}{10^N}.$$
I hope you and your friends can agree on the fact that the limit of this as $N\to\infty$ is indeed $1.$ Then, by definition, $0.999\ldots=1.$ One must keep in mind that, in any context, "$\ldots$" is shorthand for something. Here, it is shorthand for the above limit of partial sums.
Coming to the floor function, it is true that the floor of $\frac{10^N-1}{10^N}$ is $0$ for all $N\in\mathbb{N}.$ But, the floor of the limit is $1.$ This abrupt jump occurs precisely because the floor function is discontinuous at integers (in this case, it's discontinuous at $1$). Intuitively, a function being discontinuous means that the graph of the function has "jumps".
